# Flag row if one or more columns contain values

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a column that flags a row if one or more columns contain specific text.

If a row contains any of these Canadian cities – Toronto, Ottawa, Montreal, Vancouver, Calgary
[Canadian_City_Visit]=1

Please see image of table.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F448B.png)

This is the code I currently have but I’m wondering if there is a simpler way. If I have more than 100 Canadian cities or have more columns the code will be long.

```
Select Name, First_City_Visit, Second_City_Visit, Third_City_Visit, Fourth_City_Visit
    , CASE 
    WHEN First_City_Visit in (‘Toronto’, ‘Ottawa’, ‘Montreal’, ‘Vancouver’, ‘Calgary’) 
    OR 
    Second_City_Visit in (‘Toronto’, ‘Ottawa’, ‘Montreal’, ‘Vancouver’, ‘Calgary’) 
    OR
    Third_City_Visit in (‘Toronto’, ‘Ottawa’, ‘Montreal’, ‘Vancouver’, ‘Calgary’) 
    OR
   Fourth_City_Visit in (‘Toronto’, ‘Ottawa’, ‘Montreal’, ‘Vancouver’, ‘Calgary’) 
    Then 1
    ELSE 0
    END as Canadian_City_Visit
    From my_table
```

Comment: What do the columns actually mean? Surely they aren't actually named first, second, etc. This seems like a normalization problem.

Comment: What purpose should this "flag" column have? This seems to be a far better use case for an application (report, linq or whatever you use) rather than doing this in pure SQL.

Comment: Hi there. I have revised my question to make clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the Canadian cities into a list, join this list on your table and then derive the flag by checking whether one of the arising columns is not null:

```
create table tbl (
    name varchar(30),
    first_city_visit varchar(30),
    second_city_visit varchar(30),
    third_city_visit varchar(30),
    fourth_city_visit varchar(30),
);

insert into tbl values
('Mark', 'San Antonio', 'Toronto', 'Montreal', 'Philadelphia'),
('Tina', 'Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'San Francisco');

with can_cities as (
    select *
    from (values
        ('Toronto'),
        ('Ottawa'),
        ('Montreal'),
        ('Vancouver'),
        ('Calgary')) as t (city)
)

select tbl.*,
CASE WHEN coalesce(c1.city, c2.city, c3.city, c4.city) is not null then 1 else 0 end as canadian_city_visit
from tbl
left join can_cities as c1 on tbl.first_city_visit = c1.city
left join can_cities as c2 on tbl.second_city_visit = c2.city
left join can_cities as c3 on tbl.third_city_visit = c3.city
left join can_cities as c4 on tbl.fourth_city_visit = c4.city

|------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|---------------------|
| name | first_city_visit | second_city_visit | third_city_visit | fourth_city_visit | canadian_city_visit |
|------|------------------|-------------------|------------------|-------------------|---------------------|
| Mark | San Antonio      | Toronto           | Montreal         | Philadelphia      | 1                   |
| Tina | Los Angeles      | New York          | Chicago          | San Francisco     | 0                   |
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. For the "insert into tbl values", is there a way of bringing in the values without typing out all the values. I'm thinking if there are a lot more names and rows.

Comment: This is only in my example because I have to create an example table which is populated with test data. In your question you have `my_table` and usually this table exists inside your database. So you don't have to run this part at your side.

Comment: Hi there, I went with a different method than what you put above. But thank you for the feedback and information on this.